# How do I display url

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site in which people can click on names and will be redirected to the corresponding `URL`

```
id  |  name     |  url
1   |  facebook |  www.fb.com
```

I have 1,200,000,023 `URL` I want to display. `URLs` which loggedin user have not visited.
My signup information are stored in `userdb.php` like this:

```
1|username|a84894gf5sag4f684gh68fh45g|email@gmail.com|NA
```

My `display.php` is

```html
<?php

mysql_connect('mysql', '1', 'Py');
mysql_select_db('a5803761_add');
$query =mysql_query('select * from addimage order by ID DESC');


while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{

echo '<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;"><a href="'.$row['url'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: What's the problem? And question?

Comment: First of all, use `mysqli`. Second, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to store which user visited which url already. This table should have a structure like that:

```
CREATE TABLE VISITED(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
USER_ID INT,
URL_ID INT,
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
KEY(USER_ID),
KEY(URL_ID));
```

Then you have to interprep the users' click to store if they visit an url (with jQuery maybe, and send back this with AJAX) or use a redirecter PHP which logs the clicked url and then redirect the user to this.

If you consider the second one, this PHP should be something:

```
<?php
    //You should check here for the URL to be an integer
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT url FROM addimage WHERE id='.$url_id.';');
    if (mysql_num_rows($res)>0) {
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO VISITED VALUES(NULL,'.$_SESSION['logged_in_user_id'].','.$url_id.');');
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        Header('Location: http://'.$row[0]);
    }
?>
```

After that, when you list your URLs, you have to check which are the user didn't visit yet:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('mysql', '1', 'Py');
mysql_select_db('a5803761_add');
$sql  = 'select addimage.id, addimage.name, VISITED.USER_ID from addimage ';
$sql .= 'LEFT JOIN VISITED ON (addimage.id = VISITED.URL_ID) ';
$sql .= 'WHERE (VISITED.USER_ID='.$_SESSION['logged_in_user_id'].');';
$query =mysql_query('order by ID DESC');


while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
  if ($row[2] == 'NULL') {
    echo '<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;"><a href="/redirecter.php?url_id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></div>';
  }
}

?>
```

But I think it's not a good idea to list such a lot of urls in one HTML, probably the browser will eat up all the memory. Maybe you should do some kind of filter or paging mechanins.

Please consider this code as an example only, and modify it for your needs.

On the other hand, as others suggested, DO NOT use mysql_ extensions, use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: got the solution thnx

Comment: @user4527424 Then accepting my answer would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use `mysqli` or `PDO`. O, and write "http://" into link.

Comment: I realise you don't have the rep to comment, but this is a critique to OP and should be posted as a comment. Just for future reference.